# Varchar to Decimal conversion in db2

Tags: sql, casting, db2

I am trying to convert a `varchar` field to `decimal` field in `db2` but I am getting an error

`AMOUNT` field is a `varchar` field which needs to be converted to `decimal(31,3)`

Given below is my query

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(TRIM(AMOUNT),3) AS DECIMAL(31,3))
FROM TABLENAME
```

Note: `AMOUNT field (varchar)` has a `NULL` value as well
Sample values:

```
7.324088  
-42.97209  
854  
NULL  
6  
6  
350  
-6  
15.380584  
1900
```

I get the below error:

> Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function
>   "DECFLOAT". SQLSTATE=22018

Comment: The fact that it's saying `DECFLOAT` (as opposed to `DECIMAL`) indicates that `ROUND(...)` is what's balking.  This _is_ a floating-point number (has a sliding range), although because it's decimal-based it can actually store things like `.1` - is this okay?  Try to find out what type of value is actually throwing this error.  Do you have alpha characters at all in this column?  One way to try this is to do an ordered `INSERT` into some other table (**without** transactions/`ROLLBACK`), then lookup the value after the last inserted.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing like

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(COALESCE(TRIM(AMOUNT),0),3) AS DECIMAL(31,3))
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Rahul, thank you for your response. But I still get the same error. As I mentioned the varchar field AMOUNT contains a NULL value. I am guessing that is causing the error. Also few values of AMOUNT field are negative

Comment: The problem is not a `null` value - all functions in this chain are null-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your input values correspond with the same locale. I mean is the minus sign a minus or the MS Word minus? What about the decimal separator? In some languages there is a comma instead of a dot.

The coalesce function retrieves the first non-null value from the parameters. In the example:

```
coalesce (amount, 0)
```

If amount is null, it will return 0.

Are you sure you are passing a null value, or a string with the characters 'NULL', because in this case you have to convert the 'NULL' to '0' with the replace function.

```
replace (amount, 'NULL', '0')
```

Comment: Agree that separators/decimal point are possible culprit.  All functions in the chain are null-safe, so that's not the cause - although I am curious about whether it is `'NULL'`, too.