# Varchar to Decimal conversion in DB2 with empty and null values

Tags: sql, db2

I have a varchar field `AMOUNT` in DB2.

Possible table state values:

```
ID            AMOUNT
-------------------------
1             123.4578
2              NULL
2             123.78
1            -8562.85441
2            
1             0.0
-------------------------
```

Column `AMOUNT` can be empty as the second last row above depicts.

I want to do a `SUM` over the `AMOUNT` group by `ID` in a query.

The result SUM should be DECIMAL(16,2).

What will be the correct way to do that considering that the value can be both null and empty and also the number of digits after the decimal is not following any fixed format?

It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23227240/887235), but the answers given are not complete and not accepted.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: basically `if(amount is null OR amount = '') then 0 else amount`, in pseudo-code. this column should be done numerically, though. a numeric column wouldn't allow an "empty" value, which is a string. a number is either null, or an number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you want is:

```
select (case when amount <> '' then cast(amount as float) end)
from table t;
```

You don't have to worry about `NULL` values.  `sum()` ignores them.  If you want to get `0` if all values are `NULL`/blank, then add `else 0` to the `case` statement.

If you are concerned about other non-numeric values, you can try:

```
select (case when amount <> '' and
                  not regexp_like(amount, '[^0-9.]', '')
             then cast(amount as float) end
from table t;
```

Comment: Getting below error: Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-461, SQLSTATE=42846, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.CHARACTER;SYSIBM.DOUBLE, DRIVER=3.50.152

Comment: @Vicky . . . You should edit your question and show the code that you are running.

Comment: The translate statements is not correct. All DB2 translate specifications I am able to find are TRANSLATE( string_expression [, to_string [, from_string [, pad ]]] ). I am not sure how it works on other systems but IBMi will not take and empty string for to or from string.

Comment: @Peter . . . That is a really good point.  I replaced it `regexp_like()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(AMOUNT, '') = '' THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(AMOUNT, ',', '.') END AS DECIMAL (16,2))  AS AMOUNT
```

or

```
CAST (123.4578 AS DECIMAL (16,2))
+ CAST (NULL AS DECIMAL (16,2))
+ CAST (123.78 AS DECIMAL (16,2))
+ CAST (-8562.85441 AS DECIMAL (16,2))

= RESULT DECIMAL(16,2)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could add some comments or description on how or why your answer works.